# PCM device driver for raspberry pi

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, alsa, adc, dac

How to write a PCM codec device driver with long/short frame sync(Not I2S) in Raspberry Pi?
I know how to write an Alsa sound architecture device driver with I2S(write a platform device driver and codec driver) but I suppose raspberry only supports I2S in default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer! PCM has several modes for clocks! I2S is one of the others are DSP Mode A and B, left and right justified and raspbian support all of them.

For the use, another PCM mode is:
**1-** Codec driver supports it!
**2-** In the `snd_soc_dai_link` platform driver, choose them.

More information: [I2S DSP modes](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN3664.pdf) ,[Alsa Device Drivers](https://elinux.org/images/b/b5/Belloni-alsa-asoc.pdf),[DAI hardware audio formats](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/include/sound/soc-dai.h#L29).